# how to iterate in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

hi I would like to calculate the tax code of a table of people and I need to calculate a check letter and I need a cycle (ex. "for" cycle), I have documented and I have not found anything like that with regards to power bi, a Help?

Comment: This is not how power bi works. You will need to add an extra calculated column. We con only help you if you have some sample data, the problem description and how you want your end result to look like. Please provide this.

Comment: I have a 15-digit code, I have to calculate the last digit through an algorithm in which each position (even or odd) that contains an alphanumeric character that refers to a digit. After taking each respective value, the ones that refer to the even positions and those that refer to the odd positions are added. The total is divided by 26, the latter number will refer to a specific character, which will be the letter we will need to complete the code. I managed this with 16 swtichs, 7 for even positions, 8 for odd positions and 1 to do the final check. I would like to simplify everything.

Comment: As Aldert said, there are no loops in DAX but that doesn't necessarily mean you can't achieve your goal. Try opening a new question that describes what you are trying to do and includes examples.

Answer (score 0):

EXAMPLE SWTICH EVEN
questo è quanto, aiuto

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNRD7.png